# How to prevent rotate on Eyeshot?

Tags: eyeshot

My eyeshot project is to show the `.dwg` file.
But when touch the screen the screen rotate.

I want change rotate event to a pan event at native touch move event. Is this possible?
If is this impossible then I want prevent rotate screen.

Comment: You don't change the rotate event you just lock the camera to a single plane. There are already samples for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable rotation using `Model.ActiveViewport.Rotate.Enable` setting.